# access queryKey in react-qyery

Tags: react-query

I have a separate function where I am returning useQueries. Inside the function, I have a query key and query function for each query. I want to have access to the query key outside of the function. I couldn't find any documentation/resource online regarding this one. Please help!

In the example code provided below, I will need access to the queryKey at the place where I am calling the result.

```
const result = () => {
   return useQueries(
        users.map(user => ({
           queryKey :[`INeedThisValue`]
           queryFn:()=> client.getUserData().toPromise()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no such thing built-in, but you can implement it by yourself, something like that:

```
const result = () => {
  return useQueries(
    users.map((user) => ({
      queryKey: [`INeedThisValue`],
      queryFn: () =>
        client
          .getUserData()
          .toPromise()
          .then((data) => {
            return {
              data,
              queryKey: [`INeedThisValue`]
            };
          })
    }))
  );
};
```

And then get it like `data[0].queryKey` from your query result.